# Perform modal segue in container view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I need to perform a modal segue in a container view controller. The structure is similar to the `UISplitViewController`. I want to modally present a view controller only above the left table view.
I've tried to set the context of the segue to "Current Context", but nothing changed. How can I perform the segue not in fullscreen, but only in the embedded controller?

Comment: If you only want to present it on a view controller that isn't full screen, is it really a "model" presentation?

Comment: I guess yes. It should be presented modally and it's a different view controller. I think it should be treated as a modal presentation, isn't it?

Comment: You could just animate a new view controllers view over that view controller's view.